# Create trigger that checks for a date from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have to write a trigger that checks that the `MaintenanceDate` is greater or equal to the `BirthDate` of the `Plant` (which is in another table). I already wrote a function that brings the birthday of the `Plant` by `Id`.

I'm having problems If I insert a bunch of items in the maintenance table, the trigger is just not doing the job right.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrgCheckBirthDateOfPlant
ON Maintenance
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS  
    DECLARE
         @PlantId AS int,
         @MaintenanceDate AS date;
BEGIN
    SELECT @PlantId = PlantId 
    FROM inserted;

    SELECT @MaintenanceDate = MaintenanceDate 
    FROM inserted;

    IF (@MaintenanceDate >= dbo.GetBirthDateById(@PlantId))
        INSERT INTO Maitenance 
            SELECT I.PlantId, I.MaintenanceDate, I.description, I.type  
            FROM inserted I;
END
```

The tables involved are:

```
CREATE TABLE Maintenance
(
    id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    PlantId int 
         REFERENCES Plant(id) NOT NULL,
    MaintenanceDate datetime NOT NULL,
    description varchar(250),
    type varchar(15)
);

CREATE TABLE Plant
(
    id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    birthDate NOT NULL,
    height decimal (6, 1) CHECK (height<= 12000)
    price decimal(10, 2) CHECK (price > 0),
);
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Understood @marc_s ! Is there a for each or something like that that could help me?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to loop in T-SQL... a quick search will find them for you.

Comment: None I'd recommend, really - you need to convert your thinking (and coding) to a **set-based** approach. What if your `INSERT` sends in 10 rows? Are you going to reject the whole `INSERT` if even a single row has a violation of this condition? Or what's the rules for multiple inserts? You cannot selectively "accept" some rows, and reject others - it's always an all-or -nothing decision

Comment: And the other fundamental question you need to ask yourself is: do you **really** want to do this using a trigger? A trigger should be very small, very nimble, and not do any "heavy lifting", since it executes in the context/transaction of the call that triggered it. Can't you just do something like a scheduled check that would scan those tables e.g. every couple of hours and highlight / notify you of any rows that don't conform to this requirement? Does it **really** have to be right away, with a trigger?

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But it NEEDs to be a trigger, is not on my control. Im driving myself crazy

Comment: @marc_s Have you ever heard of this trick with indexed views to enforce multi-table constraints? https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to include in a trigger.  Returning extra counts is not a good thing in general.  (I am not sure what count is returned for an instead of trigger.  The rule to include the following statement might be something to investigated.  We would not want both the original insert and the replacement counts.  Does SQL Server suppress the count for the original insert if there's an instead of trigger?)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

A test if there is nothing to do.  @@ROWCOUNT (or the bigint version) is not reliable for this anymore because the source can be a merge statement.  If the trigger fires on deletes, then testing the "deleted" table is also needed.  The first statement below is good enough for inserts.  The second is okay for inserts, updates, and deletes.  (Don't use both.)

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) RETURN -- no rows inserted or updated
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) RETURN -- no rows inserted, updated, or deleted
```

Now each record in inserted needs to be tested.  It appears each can be from a different plant.  I would check the logic in the function and avoid the function.  It can be a performance killer to use a scalar function in a set based query.  Perhaps something like this.

```
INSERT INTO Maintenance 
SELECT I.PlantId, I.MaintenanceDate, I.description, I.type  
FROM inserted I
LEFT JOIN Plant p
ON p.ID = I.PlantId
WHERE I.MaintenanceDate >= p.BirthDate;
```

For testing, you don't have an "inserted" table.  You can use the real table.  Don't forget to exclude the insert.  Test it on a good sample of the data to insure you get the results you desire.  I imagine the existing data has dates that will be selected.

```
SELECT Top 100 I.PlantId, I.MaintenanceDate, I.description, I.type  
FROM Maintenance I
LEFT JOIN Plant p
ON p.Id = I.PlantId
WHERE I.MaintenanceDate >= p.BirthDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

**A much better option than a trigger,** is [a little-known trick](https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/) involving indexed views, which will enforce a multi-table constraint.

Basically, it goes as follows:

- Create a table containing exactly two rows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.TwoRows (dummy int);
INSERT dbo.TwoRows DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT dbo.TwoRows DEFAULT VALUES;
```

- Then create a view, which contains rows which *fail* your constraint, but cross-join it with this table. This view will never contain any rows.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CheckBirthDateOfPlant
WITH SCHEMABINDING  -- must be schame-bound
AS
SELECT 1 AS dummy
FROM dbo.Maintenance m
JOIN dbo.Plant p ON p.Id = m.PlantId
CROSS JOIN dbo.TwoRows
WHERE m.MaintenanceDate < p.birthDate;
```

- Then create an index on this view:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_CheckBirthDateOfPlant
  ON dbo.CheckBirthDateOfPlant (dummy);
```

Now, whenever an attempt is made to insert *or* update rows which fail the constraint, the server will attempt to maintain this indexed view. It will feed the rows into the view's joins, then cross-join it with `TwoRows`. This leaves it with two rows which have the same value for `dummy` and therefore fail the uniqueness. The insert/update is therefore completely rolled back.

---

**If you *really* want to do this as a trigger,** there are numerous issues with your existing code.

- An `INSTEAD OF` trigger can be difficult to manage, eg it would need modifying if the base table is changed. You should use an `AFTER` trigger instead.
- You can just throw an exception and prevent the insert.
- You should prevent invalid updates also.
- You must take into account multiple (or zero!) rows in the trigger tables.
- Scalar functions are really slow, and in this case unnecessary.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TrgCheckBirthDateOfPlant
ON Maintenance
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS  

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN Plant p ON p.Id = i.PlantId
    WHERE i.MaintenanceDate < p.birthDate
)
    THROW 50001, 'MaintenanceDate cannot be < p.birthDate', 0;
```

Comment: I don't see the cross join.

Comment: Sorry missed that off, fixed now